PineScript V3 to V5
x1=thisCCI >= 0 ?bufferUp1:thisCCI <= 0 ?bufferDn1:x1[1]

The above code in Pinescript V3 shows no error. It works.
In Pinescript V5, shows the following error message, referring to the last variable in the ternary -> x1[1] :
Undeclared identifier 'x1'

How is this resolved?

Starting v3, Self-referenced variables are removed. So, you need to declare the variable first.
x1 = 0.0
x1 := thisCCI >= 0 ? bufferUp1 : thisCCI <= 0 ? bufferDn1 : x1[1]


User Vitruvius provided a solution for this problem, but in general - and I wasn´t aware of this either before - you should be able to automatically convert outdated code to version 5.
In the Pine Editor in the top right corner, if you click on "More", there should be an option to convert your code, see screenshot. In this case from V3 to V4, and then you can re-do the same to go from V4 to V5.
At least, this has never failed me when I try and work on older scripts.

